# Why do I see action notification messages on other pages?

Tags: magento2, cache, session, messages

Sometimes when I added products to the cart or I type wrong my password, I see the warning message in the checkout success page.

[image: Magento 2 message success page]
[image: Magento 2 message success page]

How could I fix it?